two definitions of Hochschild Homology
There are two definitions of Hochschild homology.
$1)$ Consider a symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$, for any $A\in \mathcal{C}$ is dualizable, we have the unit,
$unit: \mathrm{1}_{\mathcal{C}}\to A\otimes A^{op}$,
and counit,
$counit:A\otimes A^{op}\to \mathrm{1}_{\mathcal{C}}$,
then we define the Hochschild homology $\mathrm{HH_*}(A)$ of $A$ as,
$\mathrm{HH_*}(A)=counit\circ unit$.
$2)$ Given any category $\mathcal{C}$,  we can define $\mathrm{HH_*}(\mathcal{C})$ as,
$\mathrm{HH_*}(\mathcal{C})=\mathrm{Tor}_{End(\mathcal{C})}(Id_{\mathcal{C}}, Id_{\mathcal{C}})$.
If we can define $\mathrm{Tor}$ on $End(\mathcal{C})$.
I wonder why these two definitions are compatible. By Morita equivalent(actually, I'm not sure whether Morita equivalent holds for the symmetric monoidal category or not), the unit can be lifted to the map,
$\mathrm{1}_{\mathcal{C}}\to \mathrm{Id}_{\mathcal{C}}$ .
But I have no idea how to push it further, as I don't know how to define $\mathrm{Tor}$ and how it can be related to $counit\circ unit$.

Can you write down the sources of these definitions? You genearlly seem to try to define traces, but the part about a Tor-functor on endofunctors does not make sense to me.

@DaniëlApol Hi, I learn it from an answer by Sasha but I fail to find a specific statement in full generality, for Sasha's answer, see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53919/hochschild-homology-of-fukaya-category-in-mirror-symmetry/53946#53946

@DaniëlApol DaniëlApol When we consider the derived category of Coherent sheaves, I think Kontsevich first achieved the second approach in his famous paper(bottom of page 44): arxiv.org/pdf/q-alg/9709040
